# How to use DocumentDB as a Vector Store with Langchain?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, langchain

DocumentDB released its vector search capabilities. Since it's MongoDB compatible, I figured we could use the same code for MongoDB Atlas seen in https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/mongodb_atlas.

I've successfully connected to my DocDB cluster however, when I run the following code

```
vector_search = MongoDBAtlasVectorSearch.from_documents(
    documents=docs,
    embedding=bedrock_embeddings,
    collection=MONGODB_COLLECTION)
```

I get an error: `ValueError: Error raised by inference endpoint: 'Database' object is not callable`.

At this point it's driving me crazy and I'm wondering if anyone has any insight on what might be causing this.

The differences from the example are that I'm using `DocumentDB` instead of `MongoDB` and Bedrock embeddings instead of `OpenAI` embeddings.

Attempted to upload documents to `DocumentDB` with `Langchain`. Expected Documents to be uploaded but was met with errors.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time to show a small and working piece of code, and full error message so we can help. See [MRE] and tatke time to take a [Tour] to know how SO works.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Vector search query API of DocumentDB is different compared to MongoDB. That is why MongoDB integration will not fully work with DocumentDB. But, now Langchain supports DocumentDB as a vector store. https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/documentdb

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35757017)